# How to create a canvas dynamically in reactjs and add refs dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, refs

Could anyone tell me how to create refs in react dynamically?

For example, I have

```
<canvas style={{display:'none'}} ref={(el) => this.image = el} > </canvas>
```

I want to create more dynamically.

Like this:

```
<canvas style={{display:'none'}} ref={(el) => this.image1 = el} > </canvas>
<canvas style={{display:'none'}} ref={(el) => this.image2 = el} > </canvas>
<canvas style={{display:'none'}} ref={(el) => this.image3 = el} > </canvas>
```

So, can I do this, or is there another way to do it?

Basically I am getting the pdf url's from server which I am converting to canvas and then to image using it.

I have already done that for one image, but to do this dynamically I will have to create those refs dynamically too and thus be able to reference them.

So, how do I do that?

EDIT : Actually I have to create img tags too dynamically and create refs for those too as I want to create dataurl from canvas and display it in image tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy to define refs dynamically using callback pattern, just specify a class variable to an empty object in constructor and then set the refs while mapping over it like

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.canvasRefs = {}
}

this.props.canvases.map((value,index)=> {
     let id = index;
     return <canvas ref={(ref) => this.canvasRefs[`canvas${id}`] = ref}></canvas>
})
```

and you can access them as `this.canvasRefs.canvas1`,`this.canvasRefs.canvas2` and so on

Comment: how does this.canvasRefs = {} in constructor help??

Comment: We are saving the refs as key value pairs in object, so instead of writing `this.cavas1, this.canvas2`, you can think of it like `this.canvasRefs = {
    canvas1: refInstance,
    canvas2: refInstance
}`, if you don't initialize an empty object, it would give you an error  in `this.canvasRefs[\`canvas${index}\`]`

Comment: i have been trying that. but when I try to access. I always get this.canvasRefs = {}
there's nothing in it although I can see the canvas's and image tags created

Comment: how and when are you trying to access canvasRefs

Comment: i am actually doing it when a modal opens.
so, then the canvas elements are created and then I try to access them within a promise.
but maybe trying to access it soon after creation , it may not have been able to get the new data yet. maybe that's why it's not finding it.
but if you have any ideas. please suggest.

Comment: yeah. adding that = ref at the end did help. now i am able to see values inside this.canvasRefs. the problem is that I am just seeing the last one there.
so, I am just getting this.canvasRefs = {canvas5:canvas}
where are all the other refs then??

Comment: oh no. it wasnt a closure issue. it was my mistake actually. got it working now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map if you have an array of canvas.

```
this.props.canvases.map((value,index)=>
<canvas ref={'canvas'+index}></canvas>
)
```

you can access it like:

```
this.refs[canvas0];
```

Comment: well, the refs I am talking about are callback refs
like this
ref={(el) => this.image3 = el}

Comment: how will you create these canvases dynamically? are you mapping it?

Comment: you mean the map function you mentioned above? 
I can do that and create the string refs but those are going to be deprecated soon. that's why i want to use callback refs

Comment: i see your point. ` ref={(index) => index}`. you can try this then

Comment: you mean map it and use the index from map??